# Saving user data from Chrome Extension to global variable, then shared for all users

Tags: google-chrome-extension, storage

Wondering if this is at all possible. I'm working on a Chrome extension where, as users browse a particular site, certain elements on the page are saved to chrome.storage.local (or chrome.storage.sync). Those elements are then called again later on a different page. However, it would be useful to allow all users to save this data to 1 global variable/source, and all users be able to read from that variable/source. Do Chrome extensions have any method of accomplishing this?

The data in question isn't anything sensitive, it's not authentication info or anything. The reason I'm hoping to do this and not just save static variables or JSON objects within a content script is that the website I'm building this for changes fairly frequently, and I would rather that data not be completely static.

Thank you!

Comment: Define "all users". All Chrome users on the same machine? All "persons" in Chrome terminology? All users browsing the site?

Comment: "All users" means all users using this Chrome extension. Also, it's a private Chrome extension. There's about a dozen or 2 dozen of us using it.

Comment: Not possible but there are lots of ways to do it for free like an appengine backend or a public google spreadsheet as sync. Too broad to answer here both.

Comment: @ZigMandel It's not a bad answer - just a negative one. Would you please make that into an answer ("no, there is no API", "you'll have to use some sort of server", "GAE is a good idea")

Comment: Alright made it an answer by popular request :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible natively but there are lots of ways to do it for free (given you have few users and load and assuming you dont surpass their free quotas or rate limits) like a google appengine backend or a public google spreadsheet as sync. For the spreadsheet case, you can store as rows or put everything on a single cell. For appengine, the datastore has free quotas for read/write and free store quota (with limits and rate limits of course).

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that the actual google store allowed the storage of minor amounts of data that all plugins could access.

Comment: not so. you might be thinking of sync storage which isnt for this case.